# Check if values in 2 columns matches & Excel to delete row if another row pass a certain condition

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Appreciate if anyone can help me on this. I have been looking for the any related questions but to no avail.

I am not sure if this can be done through VBA (if yes, better), though I am currently working on formulas (Match, VLookup) and still having a hard time.

I have three sets of columns.(Columns A, B, C)

```
DATE            INVOICE       PAYMENT*
1/10/2015       131.08
1/10/2015        1220   
2/10/2015                     1232.4*
3/10/2015                      1220*
```

The goal is to delete the rows which contains the same value found on Column B(invoice) and column C (Payment) but only if the data in column A (date) is within 3 days from the date of the match found in in both columns. Both rows within these criteria should be deleted.
01/10/2015 + 3 days = 04/10/2015 can be considered, otherwise row should not be deleted.

Desired result would be.

```
DATE            INVOICE       PAYMENT*
1/10/2015        131.08
2/10/2015                      1232.4*
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A formula cannot delete a row unless you use it in a 'helper' column to identify the rows to be deleted and then manually autofilter on the helper column and manually delete the rows. Abandon the formula solution and build a VBA sub procedure that collects a unique row identifier in a dictionary then use the dictionary keys to autofilter and subsequently delete the rows.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, thanks for the response. That is actually my initial plan to use these formula as "identifier/helper" to delete the rows. I know this is possible in VBA but I am a beginner in VBA and cannot create this on my own. I have been searching on the web for the any similar case but can't find any. If you can help me create this then that is greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: You should at least try it yourself, add your code to the question and ask a *specific* question to your code. Stack Overflow is a question/answer based site and cannot teach you how to code VBA. Therefore you might find appropriate help in a forum where someone can guide you. Reading [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) might help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have just 2 rows that would be equal which has to be deleted, created macro. Try it out,

```
Sub delrow()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Columns("A:C").Sort key1:=Range("A2"), _
      order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For j = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(i, 2) = Cells(j, 3) And Cells(i, 1) < Cells(j, 1) And Cells(i, 1) + 3 >= Cells(j, 1) Then
        Rows(i).ClearContents
        Rows(j).ClearContents
    End If
Next j
Next i
For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much Gowtham! Appreciate your response :) It works perfectly :)

Comment: Thats nice to hear!! I have made a minor change to the answer for sorting the dates properly. Use the updated answer. Please upvote if you found this useful